# Modifying/Testing Image/AnswerFile

Tags: windows-7, deployment

I made an answer file, used it with the sysprep command and then booted into WINPE and made an image of the computer.
I loaded the image on another computer and the answer file didn't quite work 100%.

Is there a way to modify the image/answer file (I am assuming since sysprep used the answer file, they are tied together now) so I can load it again and see if the modifications made a difference? I don't want to have to reconfigure and reimage the machine just to make a slight modification to the answer file.

Leon

Answer (score 0):

You want to get yourself a copy of the WAIK and check this out: [Mount and Modify an Image](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766067%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Do I then just put the new answer file in <mounted image>/Windows/System32/sysprep?

Comment: I think you're safe to copy it to any location as long as your process points back to the file.  You might also want to take a look at the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit.  It's fantastic when it comes to imaging and capturing reference computers.